# Saving a pivot table as picture?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

The following code selects the *range* of a pivot table and saves down as picture.  How would it go to select the pivot table by its name (e.g., "Pivot1") and not by the range?

```
import win32com.client as win32

import sys
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client as win32
from PIL import ImageGrab

excel_path = "C:/Prueba/GOOG-copia.xlsm"
excel = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=excel_path)
ws = wb.Worksheets('Cacaca')

win32c = win32.constants
ws.Range("A3:B8").CopyPicture(Format=win32c.xlBitmap)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
image_path = 'C:/Prueba/test.png'
img.save(image_path)
excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] this question. It sounds like your question isn't actually "Saving a pivot table as picture?", but rather "How can I select a pivot table by name?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select named ranges by using the range method:

```
wb.Worksheets('Cacaca').Range("Pivot1").Select()
```

When using the Win32 library, you can often try the process with VBA first as the Win32 calls tend to map to VBA.

Update - Here is the code to list all pivot tables in a Workbook:

```
# create dictionary of Pivot tables by sheet
dd = {}
ShtCnt = excel.Sheets.Count
for s in range(ShtCnt):
        #print("Sheet Name:", wb.Sheets(s+1).Name)
        dd[wb.Sheets(s+1).Name] = []
        cnt = wb.Sheets(s+1).PivotTables().Count
        for x in range(cnt):
                #print(wb.Sheets(s+1).PivotTables(x+1).Name)
                dd[wb.Sheets(s+1).Name].append(wb.Sheets(s+1).PivotTables(x+1).Name)
            
print(dd)
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to print all the pivot names in a workbook, by sheet? Say like: Sheet1: ['Pivot1', 'Pivot2'].... Sheet2: ['Pivot3']...